# Поле ввода input на php

Tags: php, yii2, input

Всем привет. У меня есть поле ввода от 0 до 10, как мне сделать так, что бы в данном поле по умолчанию всегда стояла цифра 0?

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'MAX_TIME')->input('number', ['min' => 0, 'max' => 10]) ?>
```

Потому что если я делаю так, то это не работает:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'MAX_TIME')->input('number', ['min' => 0, 'max' => 10], value="0") ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Второй параметр принимает аттрибуты, нужно было сделать вот так:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'MAX_TIME')->input('number', ['min' => 0, 'max' => 10, 'value' => 0]) ?>
```

Или же можно в метод `field` добавить:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'MAX_TIME', ['value' => 0])->input('number', ['min' => 0, 'max' => 10]) ?>
```

Comment: Спасибо, первый пример работает, на втором ругается: Setting unknown property: yii\widgets\ActiveField::value

Comment: @Sanvirtus странно, возможно это добавили позже или убрали наоборот, но помнется мне такое было, хотя давно с ним работал могу путать.

Comment: Блин, вот не учел я то что при создании нового элемента теперь пишется 0, но вот когда захожу в редактирование элемента, там вместо значения из бд тоже пишется 0

Comment: @Sanvirtus ну вариант так себе, но можно сделать вот так: `'value' => !empty($model->MAX_TIME) ? $model->MAX_TIME : 0`